# How Can I change color of the container when it is active or inactive in a ListView

Tags: flutter

I try to change container active and inactive color when the user currently chosee it, If I have to give more detail, I have listView which shows 10 images horizontaly, I take tohese image by for loop, I just want it when the user choose one image, Image parent container color should be different to make it easy the user understand current choice, but when user pressed other picture, only this picture active color should be appear, How can I do that, Thanks for your help..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'dart:math';

enum Sticker{
sticker1,sticker2,sticker3,sticker4,sticker5,sticker6,sticker7,sticker8,sticker9,
}
class AddMenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddMenuScreenState createState() => _AddMenuScreenState();
}

class _AddMenuScreenState extends State<AddMenuScreen> {
  Color _animatedContainerForStickersInactiveColor=Colors.white;
  Color _animatedContainerForStickersActiveColor=kColorTheme2;
  String chosenImagePath;
  List<Widget> stickerList=[];
  String menuName;
  int addScreenImageNum;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    createAddScreenImageNum();
    makeStickersWithFlatButton();
  }

  void createAddScreenImageNum(){
    Random random =Random();
    addScreenImageNum = random.nextInt(3)+1;
  }
  void makeStickersWithFlatButton(){
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
      stickerList.add(Container(
        color: chosenImagePath=="images/sticker$i.png"?
        _animatedContainerForStickersActiveColor:_animatedContainerForStickersInactiveColor,
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/sticker$i.png")),
          onPressed:(){
            setState(() {
              chosenImagePath="images/sticker$i.png";
            });
            },
          ),
      ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: kColorTheme9,
      child: Container(
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40),topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
        ),
        child:Padding(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kColorTheme2,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90)
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily:"Graduate",
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    menuName=value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border:OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      ),
                    ),
                    hintText: "Menü ismi belirleyin",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      fontFamily: "Graduate",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Text("menünüz icin yana kadırarak bir resim secin",textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Graduate", fontSize: 12),),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: stickerList,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                  color: kColorTheme7,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                ),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                  child: Text("Menu ekle", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color:  Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "Graduate", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll recommend to map your logic where you actually need it and have a stateful widget for that container so it can hold a state logic when pressed and/or selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't let the list to be rebuilt again to make new changes. So in `makeStickersWithFlatButton` all list widgets created once in `initState`. So any call to `setState` didn't make a affect

```
  var selectedIndex = -1;

  ...
  Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: =====> YOUR LIST COUNT <=====,
          itemBuilder: itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                   color: index == selectedIndex ? activeColor : passiveColor
                   child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed:(){
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                     },)
              );
          },
      ),
  ),
```

Comment: Why we exactly use builder method of ListView can you give me little info about ListView.builder ? Have a good day.

Comment: The basic listview is used for static or small length of lists. But builder version is dynamic and best for performance cases.  Have a good day Yağız

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your Container in an **InkWell**, where you can specify the **onTap** fcuntion. From there you can update your Container colour like so:

```
//set a variable for the color inside you stateful widget
Color containerColor = Colors.white;

//then in your onTap function
onTap: (){
  setState(() {
    color = Colors.red;
  });
}
```

You can also try to make your own class and then building it with ListView.builder(), which will give you the index of your items. Then you can specify an onTap, as I have mentioned before in your own class and handle the color accordingly. Once having clicked again, you simply change all other colors back to normal